# Excel - Removing Duplicates based on Second Column

Tags: excel

See below for an example:

[image: Excel Example]

I would like to remove duplicate names, but ensure that the record containing the 'blank' item would be removed. Additionally, I would not want Clark Kent to disappear - if that is their only record.

Is there a way to filter the names column so that duplicates are removed, but ensure that if there is an item that was purchased at some point, that is the record that is kept?

Thanks!

Comment: are those `N/A` an actual string or are they the error `#N/A`

Comment: Those 'N/A's are actual strings indicating that nothing was purchase for that particular trip.

Comment: Replace the `N/A` with `zzz` then sort on the first column and remove duplicates based on the second then replace the `zzz` with `N/A`

Answer (score 0):

Below a tricky example :

I added another column which i called "trick"

[image]

As you can see in this column i'm counting `=COUNTIF($B$2:$B$6;B2)`

Next step is apply filter to trick coumn to show grater than 1 rows :

[image]

Last step is apply filter to the first column filtering only not blank fields:

[image]

**Note:** i assumed you have Blank fields.

Comment: Frank, thanks for that suggestion - the 'N/A's indicate that no item was purchased, but that information is still desired to see how many customers came to the store, but didn't buy anything. So we would still want to see that Clark came to the store, but left with nothing.